# How to remove duplicate from table Lua

Tags: lua

How to remove duplicate ids from table?

```
local xx={{id=1,name=user1},{id=1,name=user1},{id=1,name=user1},{id=3,name=user3},{id=2,name=user2}} 
    
    local result = {}
    
    for key,value in ipairs(xx) do
      if value.id ~=xx[key+1] then
        table.insert(result,value)
      end
    end
    
    for key,value in ipairs(result) do
      print(key,value.id)   
    end
```

I want to print like this 1,3,2.

Comment: Are you sure you have to put them in in the first place? Lua tables satisfy this exact purpose.

Comment: @Neil What do you mean?

Comment: Set up a table from username to data? Might be easier.

Comment: I want to get unique names in my new table. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

you can take the value `name` and use it as a key, to create a duplicate free unordered table.

```lua
local t={{id=1,name='a'},{id=1,name='a'},{id=1,name='a'},{id=3,name='c'},{id=2,name='b'}} 
local users = {}

for k, v in ipairs(t) do
  users[v.name] = v.id
end

for k, v in pairs(users) do
  print(k,v)
end
```

Output

```
b   2
a   1
c   3
```

Comment: I mean table. This is not array

Comment: @ManlaibayarAmgalanbaatar I do not understand your comment.